# Pascal - Incompatible type: Got "Array Of Extended", expected "QWord" / error

Tags: sorting, types, quicksort, pascal, procedure

I am trying to sort an array of 100000 extended numbers using a quicksort algorithm, but I keep getting the following errors when calling the procedure:

- source.pas(69,26) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Array[1..100000] Of Extended", expected "QWord"
- source.pas(69,36) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Array[1..100000] Of Extended", expected "QWord"

  ```
  program test;

  type
  TVector = array of double;

  var
  N,M,i,x:longint;
  a,b,c,apod,af: Array[1..100000] of extended;

  procedure QuickSort(var apod: TVector; iLo, iHi: Integer) ;
  var Lo, Hi: Integer;
  pivot,t: double;
  begin
  if (iHi-iLo) <= 0 then exit;

  Lo := iLo;
  Hi := iHi;
  Pivot := apod[(Lo + Hi) div 2];

  repeat
  while A[Lo] < Pivot do Inc(Lo);
  while A[Hi] > Pivot do Dec(Hi);

  if Lo <= Hi then
  begin
   T := apod[Lo];
   apod[Lo] := apod[Hi];
   apod[Hi] := T;
   Inc(Lo) ;
   Dec(Hi) ;
  end;
  until Lo > Hi;
  if Hi > iLo then QuickSort(apod, iLo, Hi) ;
  if Lo < iHi then QuickSort(apod, Lo, iHi) ;
  end;

  begin
          {a[i],b[i],c[i],af[i],N,M are initialiazed here}      
          apod[i]:=(a[i]-((a[i]*b[i])/3000)-((c[i]*a[i])/40));
  end;

  begin
  QuickSort(apod, Lo(apod), Hi(apod)) ;    
  end;
  end.
  ```

  How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably because of Hi and Lo. See my answer (last section). But you have way, way more errors. Your code was probably copied from something in another language. Try to understand that code before you translate it. And debug it when you finally have it compiling.

Comment: In addition to what @Rudy told you: The `procedure QuickSort()` that you have copied from the net has as first parameter `A: array of Integer`. You have changed it to `apod: TVector` but not remembered to change the name `A` to `apod` in all places.

Comment: @Tom: a nice demonstration of what happens if someone simply copies something from the web but totally doesn't understand it. Add to that a relative lack of knowledge about the syntax of the language he wants to use, and you get something like this. Note that such a thing could happen to me too (e.g. if I copied something in, say Ruby or Ada or Scheme or Haskell), but I would not rest until I found out myself what was wrong. Actually, that is how I learned several languages. <g>

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntactical errors in your code. I did not check if your quicksort is actually correct. You can debug that.

#### Array types

You are confusing several different things:

- dynamic arrays (e.g. **type** `array of double`),
- static arrays (e.g. **type** `array[a..b] of double`) and probably
- open array parameters (**parameter** `array of double`).

Your parameter is a dynamic array type (`TVector`), but you pass a static array. These are not compatible.

To be able to pass a dynamic as well as a static array, you can use the mentioned open array parameters (note that they *look like, but are not the same as* dynamic arrays).

```
procedure QuickSort(var apod: array of Double; iLo, iHi: Integer);
```

More about open array parameters in an article of mine: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

#### Var (reference) parameters

But there is another problem: **var** parameters must have the exact type (or base type). No conversion will take place. So your *a*, *b*, *c*, *apod* and *af* parameters must contain *Doubles* too:

```
var
  a, b, c, apod, af: array[1..100000] of Double;
```

#### Unbound blocks

Then the loose `begin end`blocks after the QuickSort function don't make sense. That is not Pascal. Rather do something like this in the main block (the last `begin ... end.` — note the final `.`):

```
begin
  for i := Low(apod) to High(apod) do
    apod[i] := (a[i] - ((a[i] * b[i]) / 3000) - ((c[i] * a[i]) / 40));
  QuickSort(apod, Low(apod), High(apod));
end.
```

But note that the code above doesn't make a lot of sense. Probably all values in *apod* will be 0, since *a*, *b*, *c*, etc. are not initialized yet (so `a[i]` etc. are probably all 0).

***I have no idea where you got that code, but you may want to try to understand it, before you start translating it to Pascal.***

#### Lo and Hi

Note that you should use `Low` and `High`. `Lo` and `Hi` are something totally different: they get the low and high byte of a 16 bit word, respectively. `Low` and `High` get the bounds of arrays, sets and types.